# How to use log4j with maven and java9 in Eclipse Oxygen?

Tags: maven, log4j, java-9, java-platform-module-system, eclipse-oxygen

I try to migrate a Java8 project to Java9. The auto generated module-info.java contains an entry

```
 requires log4j;
```

and an error is shown:

```
log4j cannot be resolved to a module
```

=> How do I correctly include log4j as a module dependency with Java9?

(I have the same issue for following dependencies:
 requires hibernate.core;
 requires hibernate.jpa.2.1.api;
 requires jcommander;
 requires junit;
 requires reflections;
)

**What I did so far:**

- Installed Java 9.0.1
- Upgraded Eclipse to Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
- Changed Compliance level of my Java project to 9
- Generated module-info.java with Right click on project=>Configure=>Generate module-info.java
- Updated the plugins in my pom.xml file (also see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw) and set java version to 9:

  ```
      <!--  plugin for compile phase (and test-compile phase) -->
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
          <configuration>
              <!-- specify current java version here: -->
              <source>9</source>
              <target>9</target>
          </configuration>                
      </plugin>
  ```
- Updated log4j version in pom.xml file since log4j 1.2 does not seem to work with Java9 (see https://blogs.apache.org/logging/entry/moving_on_to_log4j_2)

  ```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
  ```

Comment: You shouldn't bind the compiler plugin another time to the life cycle. Define the maven-compiler-plugin only in pluginManagement version 3.7.0 and define source/target...no bindings.. The log4j-api does not contain a modules-info.class file so only automodule name is used which is log4j-api ? and not log4j...

Comment: If none of the `requires` is recognized, I would insist you to share the complete project structure followed and `<build>` config of your pom.xml. Also the automatic module name derived for the above dependencies are `log4j.api` and `log4j.core` respectively.

Comment: You can use the `jar` command (from Java 9) to find out the name of a module: `jar --describe-module --file $JAR-FILE` tells you by which name you have to require it. Furthermore, you can [use JDeps to identify which JARs you directly depend on](https://blog.codefx.org/tools/jdeps-tutorial-analyze-java-project-dependencies/#Getting-To-Know-JDeps).

Comment: @nullpointer The pom packaging that I want to use (I did not mention it in my question because I first thought it would not be relevant) does not include the compile phase. Therefore I had to explicitly include the compiler plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Errors in module-info.java**

Even if the **compliance level** of the project has been set to Java9, there might be shown misleading errors for module-info.java in Eclipse.

I expected that an update of the maven project would only be required if I change the pom.xml file. Now I learned that changing the module-info.java also requires a manual update of the maven project.

=> **update the maven project (Alt+F5)**

After that update my errors vanished.

I also learned that it is better to first update the versions in the pom.xml file and then generate the module-info.java. Otherwise the module-info.java will include non-existing modules like "requires log4j" instead of "requires log4j.api"

Another misleading error in module-info.java might occur due to pom packaging, see below.

**Unresolved imports**

For the case that an import can not be resolved the question might be "Which corresponding (new) module do I need for that (old) import?". What might help here:

- Search at following page for the required page:
  http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/jigsaw/ea/module-summary.html
  (lists all exported packages of the JDK-modules)
- Use JDeps on the (old) *.jar file to get a list of required jar files, e.g.

  jdeps --class-path "lib" -recursive MY-OLD.jar  >output.txt
- Use jar to find the module for a jar file

  jar --describe-module --file REQUIRED-JAR-FILE.jar

Also see:

- [What are the predefined modules in JDK9 or Which module do I need to fix dependency problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581593/what-are-the-predefined-modules-in-jdk9-or-which-module-do-i-need-to-fix-depende)
- https://blog.codefx.org/tools/jdeps-tutorial-analyze-java-project-dependencies/#Getting-To-Know-JDeps

**Re-Export dependencies**

In order to automatically make log4j visible for a grandparent project

```
grandparent => parent => log4j
```

you might want to use

```
requires transitive log4j.api
```

in parent instead of

```
requires log4j.api
```

in grandparent. Also see:

[What's the difference between requires and requires transitive statements in Java 9 module declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502453/whats-the-difference-between-requires-and-requires-transitive-statements-in-jav)

**POM packaging**

My main issue seems to be that my Java8 pom.xml file used pom packaging:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

If I remove that line, no errors are shown in module-info.java

Also see this extra question: [How to use maven with Java9.0.1 and pom packaging in Eclipse Oxygen 1a Release (4.7.1a)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228377/how-to-use-maven-with-java9-and-pom-packaging)

**New log4j version**

A. In addition to the change "requires log4j" => "requires log4j.api" I had to adapt the calling code for the new log4j version that is compatible to Java9:

private static Logger sysLog = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

to

private static Logger sysLog = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

B. log4j 2 does not have PropertyConfigurator. Also see this related question:

[PropertyConfigurator in log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043770/propertyconfigurator-in-log4j2)

C. log4j 2 does not support log4j.properties files. Previously I used

src/main/resources/META-INF/log4j.properties

for configuration. Now I use

src/main/resources/log4j2.xml

Also see

- [Log4j 2 doesn't support log4j.properties file anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485074/log4j-2-doesnt-support-log4j-properties-file-anymore)
- [Converting log4j.properties to log4j.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414639/converting-log4j-properties-to-log4j-xml)

**Working example as a reference**

[image]

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Log4JWithJava9</groupId>
  <artifactId>Log4JWithJava9</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>9</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
          </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

module-info.java:

```
module Log4JWithJava9 {
    requires javafx.base;
    requires log4j.api; 
}
```

Main.java:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;


public class Main {

    private static Logger sysLog = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

**Eclipse plugins**

In order to add log4j to an eclipse plugin, I copied the file log4j-api-2.10.0.jar in a folder "lib" and added the jar file to Java Build Path=>Libraries=>ModulePath

Instead of `requires log4j.api` I had to use `requires org.apache.logging.log4j`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work somehow.

1. I downloaded the latest Eclipse Photon Release (4.8.0), I don't know if this fix will work with older versions.
2. I changed the `module-info.java` to have the following lines:
   `requires log4j.api;
   requires log4j.core;`
3. I had to switch to an earlier version of log4j, 2.8.2.
4. I changed all my imports that say `import org.apache.logging.log4j.*;` to not use the wildcard. So they changed to: `import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
   import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;`

That's it, it works with both Maven and Eclipse.

Comment: That doesnt work for me, using the same eclipse and the same setup as described by you i get either: "log4j.api cannot be resolved to a module" in the module-info Class or "The package org.apache.logging.log4j is accessible from more than one module: org.apache.logging.log4j, org.apache.logging.log4j.core" when I do not create the module-info file.

Comment: See: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=534624  Looks like we have to wait for Eclipse 4.8.1 or even 4.9.0 Release to get this fixed.

Comment: I changed the instructions. Changed step 2 and added step 3. I have it working